# @Transactional without Rollback on errors, but working for RuntimeExceptions

Tags: java, transactions, jboss, java-ee-8

We use code in a public method that is annotated with @javax.transaction.Transactional called from a different class.

Code runs with Java EE on JBoss 7.2 and Wildfly 15.

On RuntimeExceptions, transactions are rollbacked correctly as expected.
When I manually throw a new OutOfMemoryError (as a test!) or AssertionError, the error is thrown, but the transaction is committed. Expectation is a rollback.

Implementation-wise I see org.jboss.jts//com.arjuna.ats.jta.cdi.transactional.Transactional* classes in my stack trace.

Any ideas why that is and how to enforce a rollback also on errors?

Answer (score 0):

This is happening because by default only Runtime Exceptions and its subclasses are marked for rollback. You can specify `rollbackOn` property, when using the annotation, to specify the exceptions, for which rollback should occur.

Hopefully, the [documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/transaction/Transactional.html) will help.

Comment: Thanks for this helpful hint. This explains why the rollback occurs. I was following this up, but was not getting a rollback for an OOM even with @Transactional(rollbackOn = OutOfMemoryError.class) - regardless of that I actually would wish for @Transactional(rollbackOn = Throwable.class)